# Filter data on group by query

Tags: mysql

I've got my MySQL query below:

```
select * from messages
where id in (select max(id) from messages group by Name)
```

Why does this query not work?:

```
select * from messages
where id in (select max(id) from messages where field <> 'value' group by Name)
```

Comment: The two subqueries are very different.  Can you show us some table data which illustrates this problem?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work" .

Comment: actually i'm joining... 2 table. 1 table for user and another for sales.. i just want display who sales what (last item sales)... from this data row 

1 John Car
2 Mike Bicycle
3 John Bicycle
4 John Ship

and display it like

1 John Bicyle
2 Mike Bicyle

i need to get the last item but not Ship

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what you mean by "doesn't work" - for example, whether you get an error or whether it produces unexpected results. However, going by your comment, and assuming you define "last item sales" by the maximum ID per user, I would recommend `JOIN`ing your table to a subquery that selects the maximum ID per user. For example, given the sample sales data set mentioned in your comment, you could write a query like so:

```
select s.*  
from sales s 
join (
   select user_name, max(id) as max_id
   from sales 
   where sale_item <> 'Ship'
   group by user_name
) q 
on q.user_name = s.user_name
and q.max_id = s.id
```

I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/296352/1) demonstrating the output of the query.